# How to get all the values of a key in a nested JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I'm developing a backend using NodeJS and ExpressJS, and using MongoDB to store data.
While testing the backend, I am getting a JSON object *(which I've converted in JavaScript here)* as you can see below.

```js
const errors = {
    username: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Username must contain at least 3 characters.",
        kind: "minlength",
        path: "username",
        value: "a"
    },
    name: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Name must contain at least 3 characters.",
        kind: "minlength",
        path: "name",
        value: "A"
    },
    email: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Email is not valid.",
        kind: "regexp",
        path: "email",
        value: "a"
    },
    password: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Password must contain at least 8 characters.",
        kind: "minlength",
        path: "password",
        value: "a"
    }
}
```

I want value of all the `message` keys present in the given object in form of a JavaScript array.
How to do it?

For more clarity, here is the output which I'm expecting:

```js
const arrayName = [
    "Username must contain at least 3 characters.",
    "Name must contain at least 3 characters.",
    "Email is not valid.",
    "Password must contain at least 3 characters."
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Object.values and a map like this:

```js
const errors = {
    username: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Username must contain at least 3 characters.",
        kind: "minlength",
        path: "username",
        value: "a"
    },
    name: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Name must contain at least 3 characters.",
        kind: "minlength",
        path: "name",
        value: "A"
    },
    email: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Email is not valid.",
        kind: "regexp",
        path: "email",
        value: "a"
    },
    password: {
        name: "ValidatorError",
        message: "Password must contain at least 8 characters.",
        kind: "minlength",
        path: "password",
        value: "a"
    }
}

const messages = Object.values(errors).map(err => err.message);

console.log(messages)
```